# TeXStudio not compiling .Rnw properly with "scholar" R package

Tags: compiling, texstudio, knitr

I'm working on making my CV with LaTeX, but I'm having an issue with including some R code.

I'm using `knitr` and have made a user command for TeXStudio as follows:

```
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/bin/Rscript -e "knitr::knit2pdf('%.Rnw')"
```

If I'm just using base R then there's no problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<>>=
n_cites = 44 + 7
@

I have \Sexpr{n_cites} citations.
\end{document}
```

But if I use the `get_profile()` function from the `scholar` package then I encounter an error.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<>>=
library(scholar)
prof = get_profile('IIMda24AAAAJ')
n_cites = prof$total_cites
print(n_cities)
@
\end{document}
```

And the error:

[image: error]

If I compile this same document in RStudio, everything runs fine.

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: What is the actual error you get?

Comment: Question is updated with error message. Also, it's just `scholar` not `cranlogs` that leads to an error.

Comment: Hmm. If you drop the inline R code (\Sexpr), does the chunk itself work? Try adding `print(n_cites)` at the end of the chunk, maybe we'll get a clue.

Comment: Good idea. That changed things. Updated question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34347806/troubleshooting-r-script-called-from-rscript-exe

it's a very simple fix. I just need to add `library(methods)` to my code chunk.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<>>=
library(methods)
library(scholar)
prof = get_profile('IIMda24AAAAJ')
n_cites = prof$total_cites
print(n_cites)
@
\end{document}
```

Apparently, while the `methods` package is automatically loaded in RStudio, it needs to be explicitly loaded for TeXstudio.

Comment: Actually, this is an issue with interactive vs batch mode, regardless of editor. [From the Advanced R book:](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html)

All S4 related code is stored in the methods package. This package is always available when you’re running R interactively, but may not be available when running R in batch mode. For this reason, it’s a good idea to include an explicit library(methods) whenever you’re using S4.